# Is ACF plot enough to rule out auto-correlation in my model?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, autocorrelation, acf-pacf

Do you think it's enough to check ACF plot to rule out possibility of auto-correlation in the data?

Comment: Could you please explain how generalized linear models pertain to this question?

Comment: I'm doing glm and as a part of my data exploration, I also plot ACF plots if I suspect any violation of indepence.

Comment: ACF plots of what, exactly?  Such plots of the raw responses wouldn't be relevant to the question of independence.

Comment: ACF plot of the residuals of the model itself.

Comment: Most generalized linear models do not generate residuals *per se.*  Do you have a specific type of model in mind?  What kinds of residuals are you looking at?

Comment: Models produced by glm function (families: poisson, binomial etc.) and also I tried it with glmmadmb function (family: beta). I extract Pearson residuals and use them to plot ACF plots following Zuur et al. 2009. 
I have another question by the way. If I see lines reaching beyond the blue-dashed lines in ACF plot (indicating significant auto-correlation I suppose), could it be because one of my PREDICTORS have auto-correlation in them? I'm really a newbie so please excuse me if I sound nonsense sometimes.

Comment: Dear Whuber, I still don't have any answers for the last question in my previous comment. Could you please at least take a look at it and give me some feedback? I have water level measurement as a predictor and it might have some autocorrelation in it. What should I do then?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the type of ACF plot and the amount of autocorrelation.
The $x$-series and the $y$-series generated below are both Markov chains.
The $y$-series is 'almost' equivalent to independent tosses of a fair coin.

[image]

To my eyes, the ACF plot (from R) at left shows obvious autocorrelation, while the one at right
does not.

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
set.seed(1111)
m = 200; x=numeric(m); x[1]=1; a=.3;  b=.2
for(i in 2:m) {
  if (x[i-1]==0) x[i] = rbinom(1,1,a)
  else x[i] = rbinom(1,1,1-b) }
acf(x)

set.seed(1212)
m = 2000; y=numeric(m); y[1]=1; a=.5;  b=.502
for(i in 2:m) {
  if (y[i-1]==0) y[i] = rbinom(1,1,a)
  else y[i] = rbinom(1,1,1-b) }
acf(y)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. My question is rather a general one. So is it all ok when the lags are in between blue dashed line (0.5 limit) and lags are distributed fairly evenly on both sides of the zero line?

Comment: Vertical bars are autocorrelations for various lags. Autocorrelations within horizontal bands (blue dashes) are not significantly different from 0. At the left, autocorrelation of order 1 is highly significant, a few others are slightly beyond the blue bands. At the right, there is no indication of significant autocorrelation, even though we know there is a slight Markov dependence.